# Formula to calculate different coordinates for flight routes in KML

Tags: google-earth

I need to create flight routes in Google Earth. Example from point A to point B, How do i get the equivalent middle point for both and along point A to B, there are also many different coordinates joining so that the line would be a curve.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you should use the [great-circle distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) to compute the distance of two point on the surface of a sphere, like in this case the Earth. Even [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Budapest+to+Seoul) uses this to compute direct travel times.

This would also define the midpoint for you uniquely.

Answer (score 0):

Use e.g., Perl's `Math::Trig` module. It comes complete with the great circle functions you need.